# Eloquent has in Laravel

Tags: laravel-4

If I want to find post has comment, it's like

```
Post::with('comments')->has('comments');
```

In my case, I have a comments table, only has one reply for each comment, therefore, the structure is

**comments table**

```
id
name
comment_id
```

**Comment model**

```
public function reply() {
    return $this->hasOne('comment', 'comment_id');
}
```

If I want to find topic

```
Comment::whereNull('comment_id');
```

But if I want to find out comment has reply

```
Comment::whereNull('comment_id')->has('reply');
```

It will be empty, how to find out comment has and not has reply by this structure

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `return` in your relationship:

```
public function reply() {
    return $this->hasOne('Comment');
}
```

You may also find you need to define the foreign key:

```
public function reply() {
    return $this->hasOne('Comment', 'comment_id');
}
```

Here's the docs for your reference: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#one-to-one

**EDIT:**

You may find you need to use a `hasMany` relationship instead of `hasOne`:

```
public function reply() {
    return $this->hasMany('Comment', 'comment_id');
}
```

Comment: You may need to try a `hasMany` with a foreign key. See edit.